# What use is spawning a child node process and piping it to the current node process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, pipe

I am trying to understand [this](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/streams/how-to-use-stream-pipe) example about using streams in Node from docs.nodejitsu.com.

```
 var child = require('child_process');

 var myREPL = child.spawn('node');

 myREPL.stdout.pipe(process.stdout, { end: false });

 process.stdin.resume();

 process.stdin.pipe(myREPL.stdin, { end: false });

 myREPL.stdin.on('end', function() {
   process.stdout.write('REPL stream ended.');
 });

 myREPL.on('exit', function (code) {
   process.exit(code);
 });
```

Reading the code I can see a new node REPL is created in `child.spawn('node')` and then both its stdin and stdout are piped to the stdin and stdout of the node process running the program.

What would be an useful application of this code; what can I do with it?

Comment: I still don't have enough use cases to post an answer, but basically you are piping another spawn of node into the current process, which you could use to run another Node application and have its output processed by the current application allowing some collaboration perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good use case might be to eval some code in a bit of a "sandbox" environment so that the evaled code won't pollute your current run-time environment.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and welcome to SO. I will accept this answer.